# Silverlight application for iPad

Tags: silverlight, web-applications, ipad

I want to write silverlight application for iPad device. Is that possible? i have searched on google but not getting exactly. Need proper guidance on it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash (or Silverlight) on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365286/flash-or-silverlight-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible - at all. Apple would need to make a decision to allow it to happen, but they have not. Before they would do that, it's likely they would consider Flash on iPad first and that has not been allowed either. That's the reason you haven't found anything on it.

Comment: So is there some other language that i can use to build RIA application

Comment: @mehul9595: For iPad, you could begin to explore HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without a jailbroken iPad with a silverlight application installed, which I don't think exists as of yet.

Answer (score -1):

There is no official support for Silverlight on iOS as of  **Mar 6, 2008**. As of Feb 16th 2011, nothing seems to have changed. Check this [link](http://www.macworld.com/article/132426/2008/03/silverlight_iphone.html).

Comment: That article is 2 *years* old. That's pre-iPad.

Comment: The answer is accurate, it just doesn't help answer *this* question.